# PHP APC on Windows server 2008 (PHP 5.4.3 - x64)

Tags: php, windows, apache, apc, windows-server-2008-x64

Trying to install php apc:

Downloaded http://www.mediafire.com/?53jwxu6irk48ow1

Checked all the specs:

```
x64
Php 5.4.3
Thread safe
```

But apache still gives error:

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'Z:/php_apc.dll'`

Any advice? Searched google and stackoverflow but no solutions to be found?

Comment: Just to make sure, your Apache is also a 64-bit build?

Comment: That link says it is for use on Win7, not Windows 2008. Windows is pretty awful for even the silliest things.. I would not be suprised if this is one reason also.

Answer (score 3):

It's because apc wasn't compiled for the specific version of php you are using - i had this same problem last week! Ensuring the EXACT versions matched solved the problem.